# Extracting reference level from glm coefficients

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression

I understand that the reference level is not included, but I would like a way of being able to take a fitted `glm` object and figure out what the reference levels were (ie not using knowledge of the original dataset). Is this stored anywhere in the `glm` fitted object?

Example data below:

```
> btest <- data.frame(var1 = sample(c(1,2,3), 100, replace = T),
+                     var2 = sample(c('a','b','c'), 100, replace = T),
+                     var3 = sample(c('e','f','g'), 100, replace = T),
+                     var4 = rnorm(100, mean = 3, 2),
+                     var5 = sample(c('yes','no'), 100, replace = T))
> summary(glm(var5 ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + var4, data = btest, family = 'binomial'))

Call:
glm(formula = var5 ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + var4, family = "binomial", 
    data = btest)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.6988  -1.0457  -0.6213   1.1224   1.8904  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept) -0.81827    0.73173  -1.118   0.2635  
var1         0.55923    0.27279   2.050   0.0404 *
var2b       -0.60998    0.53435  -1.142   0.2536  
var2c       -0.60250    0.51706  -1.165   0.2439  
var3f       -0.81899    0.53345  -1.535   0.1247  
var3g        0.21215    0.51907   0.409   0.6828  
var4         0.04429    0.12650   0.350   0.7263  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 137.99  on 99  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 128.35  on 93  degrees of freedom
AIC: 142.35

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

Here I'd want to know that `var1` and `var4` have no reference, but that the reference level for `var2` and `var3` are `'a'` and `'e'` respectively. Because what I would ultimately output would be a table that has `NA` for the `Estimate` for these variables at those reference levels.

---

Edit: For people that come later, I also wonder to what extent tapping into the `terms` element of the `glm` fitted object can help when combined with the answer below...

```
> btest2 <- glm(var5 ~ var1 + var3 + var2 + var4, data = btest, family = 'binomial')
> btest2$terms
var5 ~ var1 + var3 + var2 + var4
attr(,"variables")
list(var5, var1, var3, var2, var4)
attr(,"factors")
     var1 var3 var2 var4
var5    0    0    0    0
var1    1    0    0    0
var3    0    1    0    0
var2    0    0    1    0
var4    0    0    0    1
attr(,"term.labels")
[1] "var1" "var3" "var2" "var4"
attr(,"order")
[1] 1 1 1 1
attr(,"intercept")
[1] 1
attr(,"response")
[1] 1
attr(,".Environment")
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
attr(,"predvars")
list(var5, var1, var3, var2, var4)
attr(,"dataClasses")
     var5      var1      var3      var2      var4 
 "factor" "numeric"  "factor"  "factor" "numeric" 
> attr(btest2$terms, 'dataClasses')
     var5      var1      var3      var2      var4 
 "factor" "numeric"  "factor"  "factor" "numeric"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you save the fit as I show below into the variable `my_fit` you can then do `my_fit$xlevels`. For all the categorical variables you'll then see all their levels.

You can then correlate that to the model. For example, var1 is not in xlevels so it's continuous. Var2 has 3 levels (a,b,c,) and you have estimates for b and c. That means a is the reference. Var3 has categories e,f,g and you have estimates for f and g so e must be the reference.

```
my_fit <- glm(var5 ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + var4, data = btest, family = 'binomial')


my_fit$xlevels
$var2
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$var3
[1] "e" "f" "g"


> summary(my_fit)

Call:
glm(formula = var5 ~ var1 + var2 + var3 + var4, family = "binomial", 
    data = btest)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.0344  -1.1100   0.5975   0.9605   1.9985  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)   0.7321     0.8111   0.903  0.36673   
var1         -0.5061     0.2846  -1.778  0.07533 . 
var2b        -0.1929     0.5904  -0.327  0.74385   
var2c        -0.1968     0.5442  -0.362  0.71764   
var3f        -1.1015     0.5816  -1.894  0.05824 . 
var3g        -0.2004     0.5629  -0.356  0.72187   
var4          0.3945     0.1290   3.058  0.00223 **
---
```

Comment: I wish there were some way for the numeric variables to still be in `xlevels` so that way I could easily match names without having to manually extract the variables from the `glm` call and then cross those with the named elements of the `xlevels` list. Perhaps as close as we can get though.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function that extracts the `xlevels` and uses `broom::tidy` (with some additional manipulation) so that the reference level is in a dataframe with all your other terms:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

tidy_coefs_with_ref <- function(mod_obj, sep = "_"){

  tidy_coefs <- tidy(mod_obj) %>% 
    separate(term, c("variable", "level"), sep, remove = FALSE) %>% 
    mutate(variable = paste0(variable, sep))

  xlevels <- mod_obj$xlevels  

  missing_levels <- xlevels %>% 
    enframe() %>% 
    unnest() %>% 
    set_names(c("variable", "level"))

  missing_levels %>% 
    anti_join(tidy_coefs) %>% 
    bind_rows(tidy_coefs) %>% 
    arrange(variable, level)

}

btest <- tibble(var1 = sample(c(1,2,3), 100, replace = T),
                var2 = sample(c('a','b','c'), 100, replace = T),
                var3 = sample(c('e','f','g'), 100, replace = T),
                var4 = rnorm(100, mean = 3, 2),
                var5 = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 100, replace = T)) %>% 
  rename_if(is.character, funs(paste0(., "_")))

btest2 <- glm(var5 ~ ., data = btest, family = 'binomial')

tidy_coefs_with_ref(btest2)
#> Warning: Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 3 rows [1,
#> 2, 7].
#> Joining, by = c("variable", "level")
#> # A tibble: 9 x 7
#>   variable     level term         estimate std.error statistic p.value
#>   <chr>        <chr> <chr>           <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 (Intercept)_ <NA>  (Intercept)   0.904       0.835    1.08     0.279
#> 2 var1_        <NA>  var1         -0.126       0.269   -0.468    0.640
#> 3 var2_        a     <NA>         NA          NA       NA       NA    
#> 4 var2_        b     var2_b       -0.719       0.515   -1.40     0.162
#> 5 var2_        c     var2_c       -0.632       0.525   -1.21     0.228
#> 6 var3_        e     <NA>         NA          NA       NA       NA    
#> 7 var3_        f     var3_f       -0.379       0.496   -0.764    0.445
#> 8 var3_        g     var3_g        0.429       0.517    0.829    0.407
#> 9 var4_        <NA>  var4         -0.00833     0.111   -0.0749   0.940
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

(Step with `seperate` could be cleaned up.)

Also potentially relevant, here is a link to a gist where I use (an extension of) the above function with [effect coding](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqwhat-is-effect-coding/) to also extract the magnitude of the effect of the dropped level: https://gist.github.com/brshallo/f923b9b5c6360ce09beda35c3d1d55e9

Comment: This is great, thank you Bryan.  Somewhere along the way I think the default output of lm stopped putting `_` characters in the `term.labels`, so I modified the top part of your `tidy_coefs_with_ref ` function with 

```term_names <- labels(mod_obj) %>% c('\\(Intercept\\)') %>% paste(collapse = '|') ```

and then
  
  ```tidy_coefs <- tidy(mod_obj) %>% 
    mutate(variable = str_extract(term, term_names)) %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(level = str_remove(term, stringr::fixed(variable)))```